# Do you say "give a sociable compliment" when you mean you give a compliment as a way to socialize with people but it's not a true praise?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

This often happens in every culture but I think it happens more in Western countries.

That is when you socialize with your friends, you often **gush** about their things.

For example, you saw your friend wearing a new dress. In your head, you think "**what an ugly dress you're wearing**". But you don't say exactly what you think in your head. Instead, you lie about it by saying "**Wow, what a nice dress you're wearing!**".

If I translate from my mother tongue to English, it'll be "**I gave a sociable compliment on her dress**" to mean I gave a compliment just to make her feel happy but my compliment didn't mean exactly what I mean or it was just **a fake compliment!**

Do you say "**give a sociable compliment**" when you mean you give a compliment as a way to socialize with people but it's not a true praise?

Note: In English, we have "**a white lie**" which is a lie that stops someone from being upset by the truth

Can we say it "**a white compliment**"?

Comment: No, the expression doesn't exist in English. (If I thought a friend's dress was ugly, I would avoid making any comment rather than praising it insincerely!)

Comment: "I was *just being sociable* when I complimented her dress."

Comment: What we **say** when we are with the person to whom we are speaking about another person is:  to "give a compliment" using air quotes. You might want to look up air quotes. white lie does not work here.

Comment: Another phrase used is "polite fiction," which is a statement that the hearers may well recognize as untrue, but they tolerate it in order to avoid awkwardness. But it's not specifically about compliments.

Comment: @KateBunting Precisely. And if we *really* have to say something, we'd use a more neutral term, like "interesting" or "fascinating"

Comment: Can you tell us your mother tongue, please?

So far, you're verging on simple false flattery and I rather doubt that's what you meant…

Comment: hi @Tom.  the phrase is totally unknown in English.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I speak Vietnamese

Comment: Thanks and I hope that means someone here who speaks both languages well might be better able to Comment.

Either way Fattie is wholly correct. 'the phrase is totally unknown in English'

A 'white lie' by itself would work. Trying to change that into a 'white compliment' not only would not work; it would clearly demonstrate great - possibly complete - misunderstanding.

Note: you should have said 'In English, you have "a white lie"…'. Using 'we' is to claim fluency, and that prolly native fluency.

Answer (score 10):

White lie, or "flattery" (if the intention is to influence or deceive).  Or "Just being friendly and/pr polite".

The other suggestions are not idiomatic.

Comment: My wife: why did you say my mother looked nice in her striped frock? She looks hideous! Me: I was _being polite_.

Comment: I would view "flattery" a little differently from just being polite. "Being polite" might be just a way to avoid conflict or offense without trying to actually deceive, whereas "flattery" can mean trying to manipulate someone by deception, into being favorably disposed toward you. Granted, "flattery" can also be used (often humorously) to refer to polite compliments even when the hearer knows they're not true.

Comment: Telling someone their dress is pretty when it isn't is not really "a lie".

Comment: @LarsH - flattery is a gift that we present to people, whereas just praise is a debt that we owe to them.

Comment: @Lambie Sure it is. That's the textbook definition of a white lie.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is that a quote from someone? It seems pretty counter-intuitive.

Comment: @LarsH - seems pretty obvious to me. Doctor (Samuel) Johnson in issue 155 of _The Rambler_ (September 10, 1751): _Just praise is only a debt, but flattery is a present. The acknowledgment of those virtues on which conscience congratulates us is a tribute that we can at any tine exact with confidence; but the celebration of those which we only feign, or desire without any vigorous endeavours to attain them, is received as a confession of sovereignty over regions never conquered, as a favourable decision of disputable claims, and is more welcome as more gratuitous._

Comment: OK that helps explain the statement. In context I think I can see what Johnson is saying. But I wouldn't agree that praise (even honest praise) is owed, nor that flattery is a gift, in the sense of being in the best interests of the receiver. Sometimes the reverse is more true. But we digress.

Comment: @A.R. It's amazing to me how respondents come out of the woodwork.

Comment: @LarsH - some people feel that it is graceful to give praise that one thinks is deserved, and the opposite of that to insincerely flatter, especially when the motive is to benefit the giver.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey 's suggestion of "I was just being polite" is by far the most idiomatic, bravo.

Answer (score 4):

In formal gatherings, when people do not know each other, they tend to  avoid awkward silences in some way. Paying a compliment on someone's appearance is an *[ice-breaker](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ice-breaker)*, and, if sincere, can help the conversation flow.

When two strangers talk about the weather, the organiser of the event, the food being served etc. they are exchanging **[pleasantries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pleasantry)**. If I compliment someone on their attire even though I wouldn't wear it myself, I am being *courteous* (as James's answer says) and **diplomatic**. Often the speaker is struggling to find–at that moment–something positive to say.

If the person being flattered or complimented has a position of power or influence then the person who is gushing with praise can be called a **sycophant**. It's definitely not a compliment.

> SYCOPHANT
> someone who praises powerful or rich people in a way that is not sincere, usually in order to get some advantage from them:
> “Sycophants will rise to the top if a team is discouraged from giving frank opinions.”
> *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sycophant)*

What do you call a compliment that *clearly* contradicts the speaker's personal opinion? **Sarcasm** would be appropriate here, or otherwise **servile flattery** might do.

> SERVILE
> too eager to serve and please someone else in a way that shows you do not have much respect for yourself:
> “As a waiter you want to be pleasant to people without appearing totally servile.”
> *Cambridge Dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

For cases where people *say* thing things that sound nice to say, without actually following through, or without truly believing what they say, instead saying it for the ceremony of saying it; then "**paying lip service**" applies here.

[Link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lip%20service)

> **lip service** - noun
> an avowal of advocacy, adherence, or allegiance expressed in words but not backed by deeds (usually used with "pay")

Comment: This is true, but it's not usually used in the context that the OP asked about, namely, complimenting someone (e.g. on their dress).

Comment: I feel this is better than the other answers.

Comment: @LarsH: If the compliment is given because it's the sociable thing to do rather than because it's a genuine outburst; then it is paying lip service.

Answer (score 0):

## To actually answer the questions asked,

> Do you say "give a sociable compliment" ..

No. No English speaker has ever utter the four words "give a sociable compliment".

> Can we say it "a white compliment"?

No. The phrase has never been used in English. Note - it does not sound like a "clever extension" to the well-known phrase, it sounds like a non-English speaker.